# How to print sigma symbol

Tags: symbols

Picture:

[image]

Question is by far simple, how do I print the sigma greek letter?. Situation is that I want to print it as my teacher write it. As shown in the picture. I already tried Detexify with no success by the way.

Comment: Picture? `\sigma`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-math-symbol-or-character)

Comment: o_O Which picture? do you mean `$\sigma$` or `$\varsigma$`?

Comment: It's also important as to what purpose. If you're trying to write a sum, there is `\sum` that has proper spacing. If you're using sigma for something else, there's `\Sigma \sigma \varsigma`.  If you're writing greek texts, there's all sorts of unicode support.  Be more specific.

Comment: Thank you everybody for the feedback, is not a duplicate I already tried looking up for the symbols, and is none of the ones that you guys have placed in the comments.

Comment: If it's a lowercase sigma letter (used as a variable in math, not as an operator), then it all boils down to the abailability of that symbol in a font. If there's no font, then you can't use that symbol (unless you *paint* it in, e.g., TikZ). May be it's just the “calligraphy” of your teacher? An (s)he is just trying to write σ.

Comment: @Hanss: The link contains no picture, so how could we guess what you mean exactly?

Comment: I voted for keeping this open, but you should clarify what you want to get. If your teacher writes sigma that way, it's not necessarily an example to be followed.

Comment: @Bernard I am sorry I was on my phone, trying to put the question that is why I took so long to place the picture on.

Comment: @egreg All right, to be completely honest, that is the symbol that I want, He actually call it sigma (and we are working in stresses on members under certain forces so... Yeah is sigma, I know that in Materials books and everything appears the regular sigma symbol 'σ', but I actually want the one shown in the picture).

Comment: @Manuel Thank you for answering, It would be great If you teach me how to draw the symbol on tikz and actually use it in the math environment as well (and make it have different font sizes)

Comment: Off-topic comment: This 'sigma' looks like a broken tooth ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After thinking a lot about the situation I found that the best solution wasn't actually import a png version of the character. And also I found that it could be good to have a way to change the character properties.

Best way to solve the question is create the character using Tikz:

```
\newcommand{\UNALsigma}[1]{%
\scalebox{#1}{
\begin{tikzpicture}%
\draw[thick, fill] (0.7,-0.3)--(0.8,-0.3)--(0.3,-1)--(0,0)--(1,-0.1)--(1,-0.2)--(0.95,-0.1)--(0.1,-0.1)--(0.3,-0.9)--(0.8,-0.3);%
%
\end{tikzpicture}%
}}
\newcommand{\UNALsigmarc}[1]{%
\scalebox{#1}{
\begin{tikzpicture}%
\draw [thick, fill] plot [smooth, tension=0.2] coordinates { (0.7,-0.3) (0.8,-0.3) (0.3,-1) (0,0) (1,-0.1) (1,-0.2) (0.95,-0.1) (0.1,-0.1) (0.3,-0.9) (0.8,-0.3)};
%
\end{tikzpicture}%
}}
```

In that way when "typing" in the character `\UNALsigma{0.4}` or `\UNALsigmarc`, between the brackets the character can be scaled. Also `\UNALsigmarc` is a "rounded-corners" version of the character.
The output is the following:
[image: \UNALsigma{0.4} \UNALsigmarc{0.4}]

Also the character is usable in mathmode:

```
\begin{align*}
\UNALsigmarc{0.35}=\frac{P}{A}
\end{align*}
```

Obtaining:
[image: Mathmode \UNALsimgarc]

Also roundness is customizable by changing the smooth tension in the plot of the character.

Comment: Of course nobody will understand the symbol.

Comment: To me it looks like a handwritten `\nabla`.

Comment: If you're really going to go this route, at least use some font-relative unit like `ex` or `em` instead of `cm` which has absolutely no hope of scaling automatically with the font size.

Comment: @egreg Thank you so much for participating with such a useful comment. By the way I actually persisted creating the symbol because I realize all the mechanics and mechatronics department in my university DO use the symbol.

Comment: @Manuel Yeah is sort of similar, thanks for the comment (it isn't nabla if that is maybe what you meant, is sigma character for stress).

Comment: @PaulGessler Thank you so much for the advice, I actually tried but it gets kind of distorted when changing the size. Actually I didn't tried with the scalebox. Thank you so much, I'll try it and probably post it in a later time.

Comment: @Hans Find a paper written by those who use the symbol and see what they use in LaTeX.

Comment: @Manuel Probably the regular `\sigma` symbol (not probably, that's almost for sure, but differ of what is handwritten), as this one wasn't available (now it is available).

Answer (score 8):

I don't recognise the image as a sigma. Unicode has three variant lowercase sigmas

```
U+03c2 GREEK SMALL LETTER FINAL SIGMA
U+03c3 GREEK SMALL LETTER SIGMA
U+03f2 GREEK LUNATE SIGMA SYMBOL
```

which look like

> ςσϲ

or as an image

[image]

---

If you are convinced you want the letter shape you drew just save it as a png or (better if you can) a scalable format such as pdf, then you can do

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath}

\newcommand\bentpaperclip{\includegraphics[height=1ex]{bentpaperclip.png}}

\begin{document}

\[\sigma \neq \varsigma \neq \bentpaperclip\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: @ David Carlisle: For me it's a small (non-final) `σ`, with some awkwardness due to the fact it's not that easy to make a drawing with a mouse

Comment: @Bernard I was going to suggest a guess but decided to leave it to the OP:-)the non final form is a possibility but as drawn it's an open curve so topologically equivalent to the other two and not to the one you suggest so (since I was once a topologist) I wasn't prepared to rule out the other possibilities:-)

Comment: @Bernard No actually I am pretty sure of what I draw (was'nt using a mouse). And none of them is the symbol.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thank you for answering, by the way but I am pretty sure none of those symbols is. And thanks for the edit (As I said before I was on a phone and it's not easy to post a question from there).

Comment: @Hans If it isn't one of those symbols then are you sure it's a sigma? (unicode has pretty good coverage of classical and modern European scripts and of math notation, so if Unicode doesn't think it's a sigma then I'd be inclined to believe it...)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I want to be completely honest with you, I don't know much about this subject, but I already made my research (on wikipedia and google) and I didn't find the sigma symbol as the shown in the greek letters history. My teacher keeps stating that is the sigma symbol and actually he makes another symbol (can't remember the name but it was a greek one to) that is exactly the same but backwards (horizontally only).

Comment: @Hans Teachers can be wrong:-) But anyway I updated the answer with something you could use.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you for your patience and your answer, I was actually looking forward for something a lil bit more professional. I mean you can see the difference from a mile.

Comment: +1 for `\bentpaperclip`

Comment: @Hans a professional publication would use a real sigma, what else can I say?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Is not about saying anything, you know?, thank you so much anyway.

Comment: @Hans the image above is literally a cropped version of your image, you could produce something more closely matching your fonts if you spent a bit of time in any drawing program, the point of the edit was to show the possibility of using the symbol from an image (since it doesn't appear to be one you will find in a font)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yeah, yeah I know but it would be fantastic what Manuel typed in the comments, a version made in tikz is just that I don't know how to. And I actually needed like $\bentpaperclip_x$ (thanks for the name for the letter by the way I think it fits as hell).

Comment: @Hans I am greek and David Carlisle is right. The first symbol σ is the sigma that goes inside of the words. The second one ς is the sigma that goes at the end of the words. The sigma that you draw it is my belief that is the first one and not something different because there is not such a letter in the greek alphabet. Your teacher I believe was just in a hurry so that is why it isn't very similar to the ones seen in this answer. Hope that helped!

Comment: @Hans --- if your teacher uses Microsoft Word, will you do that as well?

Comment: @IanThompson my teacher does not use Word.